# Realm.io Optional Properties

Tags: ios, realm

I have just started using Realm.io on iOS and am attempting to populate objects but am getting the following:

`Invalid value nil for property`

How can I make a property optional?

Answer (score 8):

You can’t at the moment. Only relationships can be nil at this point. We’re working on adding this soon though!

Comment: Any update on this at all? Having optional parameters is essential for an app I'm building for our client. Without it I'll have to add some code smell.

Comment: It is still in the works. In the meantime, perhaps you could consider wrapping your properties in object? These _can_ be optional. So instead of having, say, a string and an int as properties, you would have two object properties, one which only contains a string, and one with only an int.

Comment: I went for implementing
+ (NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues;
providing default empty values. It did the trick.

Comment: any proper way to do this??

Comment: Good timing — we are actually implementing this in our core right now. It’s taking a long time because we have to implement support type by type, determine how it is treated by queries, etc. In the meantime a good workaround is too wrap those properties in a RLMObject, which can be optional: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/628#issuecomment-56765986

Comment: Any updates on this? As much as I want to use Realm, lack of optional properties is kind of a deal breaker :(

Comment: Yes, we shipped a couple of betas in this thread. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/628 Now working on merging + releasing this, potentially in our very next cocoa release. You can follow that issue on GitHub to be notified of future updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible since 0.96 for the following properties, see [realm.io](https://realm.io/) for the latest documentation.

`NSString *, NSDate *, NSData *` now allow nil by default. You can disallow   setting a property to nil by overriding the `+requiredProperties` class method and including the names of the properties which you want to disallow nil for. Accessing a Realm file created with a previous version will automatically convert these properties to nullable in the file itself, unless explicitly marked not to do so in `+requiredProperties`.

Optional numbers can be stored using an `NSNumber *` property which is tagged with the type of the number. You can use `NSNumber<RLMInt> *`, `NSNumber<RLMBool> *`, `NSNumber<RLMFloat> *`, and `NSNumber<RLMDouble> *`.

Comment: Can you augment the answer to detail how to convert an existing non-optional property to an optional property (migration)?